# How do I make this grammar LL(1)?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, theory, ll-grammar

Lets say I have this grammar

```
E -> T+Ex | F
T -> T*Fy | w
F -> E | z | ε
```

Now I need to make it LL(1). I've been following the steps but the solution I came up with doesn't seem quite right.
Fist lets eliminate ε-productions

```
E -> T+Ex | F | T+x
T -> T*Fy | w | T*y
F -> E | z
```

Now we'll eliminate cycles

```
E -> T+Ex | T+x | z
T -> T*Fy | w | T*y
F -> T+Ex | T+x | z
```

No we'll eliminate immediate left recursion

```
E -> T+Ex | T+x | z
T -> wT'
T' -> *FyT' | *yT' | ε
F -> T+Ex | T+x | z
```

Finally we'll replace certain RHS productions where `T` occurred

```
E -> wT'+Ex | wT'+x | z
T -> wT'
T' -> *FyT' | *yT' | ε
F -> wT'+Ex | wT'+x | z
```

Now this doesn't seem to be LL(1) to me since the parse table generated by this will have multiple entries for several of the terminals. What do I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, so out last step we have this configuration

```
E -> wT'+Ex | wT'+x | z
T -> wT'
T' -> *FyT' | *yT' | ε
F -> wT'+Ex | wT'+x | z
```

We now need to perform left-factorization to remove productions of the form

```
S -> aB | aC
```

And make them into the proper form

```
S -> aA
A -> B | C
```

Using this we can transform our grammar into

```
E -> wT'+E' | z
E' -> Ex | x
T -> wT'
T' -> *T'' | ε
T'' -> FyT' | yT'
F -> wT'+F' | z
F' -> Ex | x
```

Since `F` and `F'` are the same as `E` and `E'` we can just remove this production so we are left with.

```
E -> wT'+E' | z
E' -> Ex | x
T -> wT'
T' -> *T'' | ε
T'' -> EyT' | yT'
```